# I want to create a currency table for my project

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Sorry for grammar mistakes. I want to create a currency table for my project which will use for adding currencies of different countries. This is my currency table but I'm confuse that this will good or not for project, so should I delete or add more columns in this table? Please help me.

### currency

```
id | symbol | description | country | date_added | date_updated
```

Comment: Have a look at PHP intl and especially the [NumberFormatter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.formatcurrency.php).

Comment: @AyazShah Without knowing what you're doing with the currency, it's extremely hard to advise what information you should or should not store.

Comment: Good question @Alex.Ritna... I use currency for products. When user select a product in shop page then a select bar will visible with product and show the currency and its counrty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you better should have two tables.
One table for `currency` descriptions with fields `id`, `symbol`, `description`, `country` and other table related to this for daily currency `rates` with fields `currency_id`, `rate`, `time_updated`.

Comment: Thanks for response @DarkSide. But when you can do it with one table then why we used two tables?

Comment: Because you don't need to repeat currency symbol, description and country fields for each day each currency. Only currency rate changes, so keep them separate from other fields.

Comment: The change of exchange rate is most time not interesting for your service, so this approach would create more unnecessary data then using a single column which gets updated.

Comment: If you don't need to save historical rates of currency, then of course you don't need two tables :) All depends of your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The question is if you really need the date_added. I think this is a information which is not really required.

If you want to update it regulary, I would implement a column "**rate**", which gives you the value in comparison of Euro or US$ as example. This way people can get a better impression how much 1 Unit of the currency is worth.

Otherwise this looks to be quite okay.

Comment: date_added definitely is useless field

Comment: Okay.. Should I delete date_added..?

Comment: After reading your comment what your service does, yes, go for it. It does not give yourself or your customers any value.

Comment: I don't understand why you tick the answer which gives you are more complex aproarch which is not evne required, but alright.